# Ansible ios_config run conditionally if parent exists

Tags: ansible

I have a play below that create an interface and configures it but I would only like to run this section if the interface doesn't already exist in order to prevent accidentally modifying an existing interface. Is that possible?

```
- name: create interface
  ios_config:
    parents:
      - interface Loopback98
    lines:
      - description Testing Ansible
      - ip address 10.0.0.98 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: According to [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/network/getting_started/first_playbook.html#gathering-facts-from-network-devices), running `gather_facts: yes` or [`{"ios_facts": {"gather_network_resources": true}}`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/ios_facts_module.html#parameter-gather_network_resources) should produce ansible_facts containing the existing interfaces; have you tried examining `- debug: var=hostvars` to see if the list of interfaces is there?

Comment: Yes and they are but I don't know how to conditionally run a play if the interface is there. I think I need to use "when: ..." But how would I check for one line in the entire interface output to make a working "when" statement?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Jinja2 expressions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#other-operators), such as `when: '"abc" in ["abc", "def"]'`?